# Clicking notification without starting activity Android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm new to android programming and I just learned how to make a `notification` via an `Intent` and a `PendingIntent`. I wondered if I could make this notification clickable (link to my `MainActivity`) without starting a new `Activity`.

This is what I have right now (`AlarmReceiver` excluded) as a function in my `MainActivity`:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

I reckoned I should change "this" to something else, but I wouldn't know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is it that you want to happen (or not happen)? Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the notification Builder, in my case the compat builder.

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder
```

Setting the content, I've got mine from the params. You have to replace them with your respected once.

```
builder.setContentTitle(params.getTitle())
            .setContentText(params.getText())
            .setWhen(params.getTime())
            .setTicker(params.getTickerText())
            .setPriority(params.getPriority())
            .setOngoing(params.isOngoing())
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setAutoCancel(params.getAutoCancel())
            .setStyle(params.getStyle());
```

Creating PendingIntent and also adding it to the Notification through the builder. This intent should be pointing to your Launcher Activity and from there you can handle it in OnCreate.

```
 builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Then push the notification

```
 mNotificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

You can also make these notifications pointing to a BroadCastReceiver and handle a click on the notification from there, on its onReceive method.

Answer (score 0):

```
       Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
       alarmIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),    pendingIntent); ...try this
```